# Get the initially requested route after being redirected to login page

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

In my app, when a user tries to access a route behind a firewall and gets redirected to login, they are given the opportunity to create an account. After creating the account and successfully logging in, I'd like to redirect them to the initially requested page.

However, I've not been able to work out how to get access to the route they initially requested before the security kicked in. Any help?

I'm not using FOSUserBundle, and I'd like to avoid it if possible, as I'm quite far into development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default user redirected to the requested page. This behavior defined in [DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php).

Comment: That's the link I was hoping to get. Thanks, that's super helpful :)